# Azure Data Factory Pricing per activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

On this page it says that

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/

```
PRICE: First 50,000 activity runs—$0.55 per 1,000 runs 


Example: copy activity moving data from an Azure blob to an Azure SQL database;
```

If i understand this correctly, if for example i make an activity that reads a blob that contains text and then puts that text into sql database, that would cost per 0.55 per 1000 runs? That is very expensive.

Note usually one can have multiple activities in a pipeline.

So if i read a blob from azure storage account, put it in sql azure, then send an e-mail, you already have 3 activities.

In azure function I pay about 0.20 dollars per million executions and $0.000016 per gb per second. ( that means that If i have 1 gb photo in memory for 2 seconds i pay 0.000016 x 2 = 0.000032.

Is the pricing massive or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

That current pricing link for ADF is during ADF V2 preview and is .55 for every 1000 runs up to 50k runs, .50 / 1000 after that.

So, if you have a copy activity that runs 1000 times, you pay .55 + data movement cost / hr.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why would you compare it with Azure Functions, they are different services with different pricing models.

Regarding Data Factory, on top of the activities, you have to consider the data movement cost also.

I don't think its massive as you say, considering its secure, fast, scalable, etc. If you are a big company that is moving its important data to the cloud, you shouldn't be afraid of paying 10-20 dollars a month (even 100!) to get your data to the cloud safely.

Also, if you are using a massive amount of activities and the price is out of control (in the super rare case it does), you are probably not engineering well enough your data movements.

Hope this helped!